# War deploy from Tomcat 7 to Weblogic 10.3.5 doesn't work

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I'm trying to deploy a war file into Weblogic 10.3.5 but it's now working. 
The same file is deployed with success in Tomcat 7 and the app runs gracefully.

However, when I try to deploy it in Weblogic using the default settings for the deploy plan and so on, it raises a NullPointerException error in a ServletContextListener implementation that I have.
My question is: Do I need to change something in the application like to add the weblogic.xml file? Do I need something else?

I noticed that if I point my deployment to a folder which contains the exploded war content, the application runs with a few errors, but at least the main screen opens fine (it's an applet based application).

**UPDATED

Here is the exception I'm getting when I try to start the app.

```
####<Oct 29, 2012 5:27:12 AM PDT> <Warning> <HTTP> <ip-0A2E9E72> <AdminServer> 
<[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> 
<<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1351513632838> <BEA-101162> 
<User defined listener artemispm.web.ui.gwt.server.A7WebStartupListener failed: 
java.lang.NullPointerException.java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:394)
at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:143)
at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:729)
```

Comment: 'I'm trying to deploy a war file into Weblogic 10.3.5 but it's _now_ working'. Shouldn't it be _not_ working

Comment: Hi, added the exception. Thank you.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not an old fashioned forum. There's no need to yell "SOLVED" in titles. Just post an answer and when time allows it, mark it accepted. Questions with accepted answers appear different in the listing which can be interpreted as "solved". Also, the search supports filtering questions with accepted answers only. So there's absolutely no need to add extra (and disturbing) distinguishment :)

Comment: Thanks for adding the stack trace to the question.  For future reference, the more interesting lines of the stack trace are the ones you omitted - the ones where your code is doing the work, not the JDK or the app server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what was the issue. Weblogic was returning null when I was trying to call

```
String path = servletContextEvent.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

Then I was trying to add that path variable to the System properties and according to the java documentation it throws a NullPointerException when we try to add null values to a HashMap.

So, in order to enable web applications to retrieve the real path we need to configure a property from our Weblogic's domain. I went to Weblogic's console, then clicked on domain's name -> Web Applications tab. Find the Archived Real Path Enabled option and check it. You'll need to restart the server.

Thanks everyone,

Gyo